# How to use JournaledGrain for event sourcing

Tags: c#, orleans

I am beginner in ms orleans. I want use JournaledGrain send an event to its listener(s). Here is what i tried.

```
public class MyJournaledGrain : JournaledGrain<State, Event>, IJournaledGrain
{
    public MyJournaledGrain()
    {


    }

    public void RaiseEvent()
    {

        Trace.WriteLine(" hi ");
        this.RaiseEvent(new Event());
        this.ConfirmEvents();

    }


    protected override void OnStateChanged()
    {
        // some thing ...
        base.OnStateChanged();
    }

    protected override void TransitionState(State state, Event @event)
    {

        base.TransitionState(state, @event);
    }
}
```

In OnStateChanged method i can get raised events but sender and receiver are in one class. I want some thing like pub/sub pattern. It is possible to achieve this by ms orleans ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Event sourcing and pub/sub are 2 independent things:

- Event sourcing is for state persistence of a grain
- Pub/sub is for messaging between grains

For pub/sub you need Orleans Streams: https://dotnet.github.io/orleans/Documentation/streaming/index.html